# Symfony2 a search form with approximate results

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am trying to make a search form... Everything works fine, however right now the search works only if I search for a specific object, and the letters have to be identical to the products name.

The form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
//            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('search'))
            ->add('search', 'text', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Search for products',
                ),
                'label' => false))
                ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        if ('POST' === $request->getMethod())
        {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            $data = $form->get('search')->getData();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('searching', array('data' => $data)));
            }
```

How I find products:

```
$products = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findProductsBySearch($data);

    public function findProductsBySearch($data)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $qb->where('a.model=:model');
        $qb->SetParameter('model', $data);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    }
```

If I search for example Test1 - the product is found. But if I write Test - no products is found.

What I want to achieve, is to find all the products that has the string given in the form.

For example if I have 3 products: Test1, Test2, Test3... If I type Test and submit, I should find all of these products... And no matter if the leters are in lowercase or uppercase.. How can I do that in PHP and Symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$qb->where('a.model LIKE :model')
   ->setParameter('model', '%'.$model.'%');
```

It will give you everything that contains your `$model`. If you only want the results starting with your `model` you can delete the first %.

Hope this helps.